# Open quote is expected for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type "EditText"

Tags: android, xml

It's the first app I try to write for android and I've seen more people who have this problem but I cannot seem to find the answer. It's supposed to have the wrong type of " but there isn't any. Plus, all the text boxes are written the same but only the first one has the error. I even tried switching them but only the first one gets it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <EditText
            **android:id=@+id/editText1** //(the error comes here)
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:width="1dp">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
         <EditText
            android:id=@+id/editText2
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:width="1dp">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText> 
          <EditText
            android:id=@+id/editText3
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:width="1dp">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
          <EditText
            android:id=@+id/editText4
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:width="1dp">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Determinar"
              android:onClick="determinar" />

    </LinearLayout>

Thanks for your time!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error not only there, but also through out the layout

you should surround `@+id/yourid` within quotes

i.e

```
android:id="@+id/editText3"
```

Comment: if I quote it as you said it gives me: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Open quote is expected for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type 
  "EditText".